# How to add types to this function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to add types to this function. Any help?

```
import { Either, left, right } from './Either'

type validationData<T> = {
    field: string
    value: T
    validatorClass: {
        value: () => T
        create(value: T): Either<Error, { value: () => T }>
    }
}

export function propsValidator<Value>(validationData: validationData<Value>[]) {
    const errors: Error[] = []

    const asd: { field: string; value: { value: () => Value } }[] = []

    validationData.forEach((data) => {
        const result = data.validatorClass.create(data.value)

        if (result.isLeft()) {
            errors.push(result.value)
        } else {
            validData[data.field] = result.value
            asd.push({
                field: data.field,
                value: result.value
            })
        }
    })

    const validData = asd.reduce(
        (acc: Record<string, { value: () => Value }>, curr) => {
            acc[curr.field] = curr.value
            return acc
        },
        {}
    )

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        return left(errors)
    } else {
        return right(validData)
    }
}
```

Validator class example

```
import { z } from 'zod'

import { Either, left, right } from '@core/logic/Either'
import { logger } from '@infra/logger'

import { InvalidCreatedDateError } from './errors/InvalidCreatedDateError'

const CreatedDateSchema = z.date()

export type TCreatedDate = z.infer<typeof CreatedDateSchema>

export class CreatedDate {
    private readonly createdDate: TCreatedDate

    get value(): Date {
        return this.createdDate
    }

    private constructor(createdDate: TCreatedDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate
    }

    static validate(createdDate: TCreatedDate): boolean {
        try {
            CreatedDateSchema.parse(createdDate)
            return true
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(`CashFlow.CreatedDate.validate: ${error}`)
            return false
        }
    }

    static create(
        createdDate: TCreatedDate
    ): Either<InvalidCreatedDateError, CreatedDate> {
        if (!this.validate(createdDate)) {
            return left(new InvalidCreatedDateError(createdDate))
        }

        return right(new CreatedDate(createdDate))
    }
}
```

```
export interface DomainError {
    message: string
}

export class InvalidCreatedDateError extends Error implements DomainError {
    constructor(createdDate: Date) {
        super(`...`)
        this.name = 'InvalidRecorderIdError'
    }
}
```

Function entry example

```
[{
        field: 'createdDate',
        value: raw.createdDate,
        validatorClass: CreatedDate
}]
```

This function should receive an array of objects that would have fields, value and validatorClass properties. The function would validate all of them and return all the errors found or an object containing all instances of the validating classes with the values ​​that can be accessed by get value().

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre].  Ideally it would be a single code block that we can paste into our own IDEs and immediately see the issue you're facing without unrelated problems or inclusion of other things, so we can get to work.  Among other things that would imply the code should have no third-party dependencies (unless your question is *about* such third-party dependencies) and no dependencies on private code we don't have access to.  Good luck!